# Xamarin.Ios How to send ADPU Command (NFC)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, nfc, iso

I try to develop an App (in xamarin.ios) that simply when find a TAG send an ADPU Command and Recive a responce.

I read lot of documentation but nothing to explain how can I send an ADPU command.

I think is possible, for example reading this: (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/nfciso7816tag/3043835-sendcommand)
or this (https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/118499)

I search if possible:
-Documentation / article / something to read about argument
-Or better a sample code

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: you're linking directly to the method for sending a command.  What don't you understand, or where are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks for reply Jason, the link above is for Swift code and I have to implement this code in Xamarin.Ios that works in C#

Comment: yes, but Xamarin has the same class structure and methods.  See https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/06041ab37f153c4e14f0e4a6036e8062a6d72d74/src/corenfc.cs#L918

Comment: You are in true Jason.. Thanks